# Multiple programs giving black screen when run on Nvidia GPU

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10

since saturday my laptop is giving black screens when I run programs like Atom or Discord. The program load correctly and shows briefly when you resize it. I got the best result with the Minecraft launcher displayed in the .gif below

[image: example]

I've tried to reinstall the Nvidia control panel and drivers and install the newest updates but it's not solved.

I am running windows 10 Creators Update and have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 950m

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: The correct question is what did you do on Saturday to cause this ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев I think he installed the W10 Creators update.

Comment: I can't reply on my own thread so I have to use this; I updated to W10 creators update and suddenly I got a blackscreen using any program that runs on my gpu except games like rocket league etc. Atom, Discord, Minecraft Launcher are the ones I tried

Comment: I want to say this may fair better on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) since this seems to be happening system wide.  It's technically not really about gaming besides the fact that it affects your Minecraft Launcher too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about graphics card troubleshooting. Graphics cards are not considered gaming specific hardware, so this should be asked at SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem before.  It occurs when Windows 10 has decided it has the better driver available during an update and updates your nVidia drivers with a version of its own.  This is especially common on laptops, where the GPU itself is usually not on a discrete, uniform graphics card.  While updating the driver through nVidia may fix the issue, it's not uncommon to have to go back to the manufacturer and update the driver there when using a mobile computer like a laptop. Many laptop manufacturers have their own drivers for their hardware which are better suited to their custom configuration than the Forceware reference package.